# Autoresize css tooltip

Tags: html, css, resize, tooltip, autoresize

i have this css tootlip code:

```
    a.tooltips {
      position: relative;
      display: inline;
    }
    a.tooltips span {
      position: absolute;
      width:140px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background: #000000;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      visibility: hidden;
      border-radius: 6px;
    }
    a.tooltips span:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -8px;
      width: 0; height: 0;
      border-top: 8px solid #000000;
      border-right: 8px solid transparent;
      border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    }
    a:hover.tooltips span {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 0.8;
      bottom: 30px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -76px;
      z-index: 999;
    }
```

I want it to auto resize based on the text lenght. (long or short)..how i can do it? Thank you.

Comment: what if you remove `width:140px;` from the span? Maybe you could replace it with a `max-width`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of; `width:140px;` from the class `a.tooltips span`